# How to reproduce Codeship's non-Docker CI environment locally?

Tags: continuous-integration, codeship

Is there a way to reproduce Codeship's CI environment locally when *not* using Codeship's Docker support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't share the build VMs for our classic infrastructure publicly at the moment. I'll bring this up with our engineering team, but I can't make any promises right now on what they'll decide.

We do however have a SSH debug feature available, that will allow you to access a build VM with your code cloned via SSH and run & tweak commands that way. See https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/ssh-access/ for more information.